# Oracle sql nested aggregate functions

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In nested aggregate function using group by clause ex `max(avg (salary ))` first salary is calculated for each dept assuming grouping is done by dept and then max of that is selected . Now what I dint understand is that how multiple aggregate function works

```
 select max(dept), max(avg(salary))
 from employee
 group by dept;
```

How will such a query work? Which aggregate function executes first? Can any one plz help me, I am new in SQL.

Comment: Tip 1, don't group by columns also used as arguments to aggregate functions. (dept...)

Comment: Select max (salary), max(avg(salary)) from employee group by dept

Comment: Above query gives me error why so??

Comment: Your query makes no sense. MAX(salary) for each department is OK, but what do you expect when you say maximum average salary for each department?

Comment: `select max (salary), max(avg(salary))` is the same with `salary, avg(salary)`. That's why the query above give you an error.

Comment: Select count (salary ) , max(avg(salary)) works fine why???

Comment: Max (avg( salary )) means I want to find avg salary of each dept and then max of all dept

Comment: Somebody could help you if you provide sample data and desired result.

Comment: Well I don't have any desired output . I m learning sql and trying to figure out how multiple nested aggregate functions work. How execution happens for such query

Comment: How can you not have desired output? There must be some sample input data and expected output for your query - otherwise, how will you ever know whether your query behaves as expected?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have this table:

```
create table employee (dept number(4), salary number(12));
insert into employee values (10, 1000);
insert into employee values (10, 5000);
insert into employee values (20, 2500);
insert into employee values (20, 3500);
insert into employee values (30, 2000);
```

So average salaries in departments are:

```
select dept, avg(salary) avs from employee group by dept order by dept;
DEPT        AVS
----- ----------
   10       3000
   20       3000
   30       2000
```

Your query shows maximum value of department_id (30) and maximum value of average salary per department. These values are **unrelated**. 
In other words your SQL shows maximum values from previous output.

```
select max(dept), max(avg(salary)) from employee group by dept;
DEPT        AVS
----- ----------
   30       3000
```

---

If you want to show department(s) with highest value of average salary you have several options.
Everything depends on what you want to do if there is more than one such department, like in my example where two (10 and 20) have equal, highest average:

```
-- use HAVING clause with subquery (old school):
select dept, avg(salary) avs
  from employee group by dept
  having avg(salary) = (select max(avg(salary)) from employee group by dept)
  order by dept;

-- use analytic MAX() function:
select dept, avs
  from (
    select dept, avg(salary) avs, max(avg(salary)) over () max_avs
      from employee group by dept)
  where avs = max_avs order by dept;

-- use analytic DENSE_RANK():
select dept, avs 
  from (
    select dense_rank() over (order by avg(salary) desc) rnk, dept, avg(salary) avs 
      from employee group by dept)
  where rnk = 1 order by dept;

-- if you want ONLY ONE ROW use MIN(...) or MAX(...) KEEP (DENSE_RANK...)
-- this returns department with lower ID:
select min(dept) keep (dense_rank last order by avg(salary)) dept,
       min(avg(salary)) keep (dense_rank first order by avg(salary) desc) avs
  from employee group by dept;

-- this returns department with higher ID:
select max(dept) keep (dense_rank last order by avg(salary)) dept,
       max(avg(salary)) keep (dense_rank first order by avg(salary) desc) avs
  from employee group by dept;
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1f38/1)</sup>